# AJAX + Spring MVC: Cannot find destination

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

I have a form which **should** send user input via ajax to my spring mvc controller.

But I always get an Error as you can see below. I implemented into *getSearchResultViaAjax* a *System.out.println("in getSearchResultViaAjax")*;

but it is never called in the console. Any idea how I could fix that?

**Error Message:**

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"timestamp\":\"2018-03-24T18:33:14.749+0000\",\"status\":404,\"error\":\"Not Found\",\"message\":\"No message available\",\"path\":\"/$%7Bhome%7D/search/api/getSearchResult\"}",
    "responseJSON": {
        "timestamp": "2018-03-24T18:33:14.749+0000",
        "status": 404,
        "error": "Not Found",
        "message": "No message available",
        "path": "/$%7Bhome%7D/search/api/getSearchResult"
    },
    "status": 404,
    "statusText": "error"
}
```

I tried in AJAX also paths like:

url: "/search/api/getSearchResult"

url: "search/api/getSearchResult"

and get this then for example

```
{
    "readyState": 4,
    "responseText": "{\"timestamp\":\"2018-03-24T19:48:43.638+0000\",\"status\":500,\"error\":\"Internal Server Error\",\"message\":\"Error resolving template \\\"search/api/getSearchResult\\\", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers\",\"path\":\"/search/api/getSearchResult\"}",
    "responseJSON": {
        "timestamp": "2018-03-24T19:48:43.638+0000",
        "status": 500,
        "error": "Internal Server Error",
        "message": "Error resolving template \"search/api/getSearchResult\", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers",
        "path": "/search/api/getSearchResult"
    },
    "status": 500,
    "statusText": "error"
}
```

**Controller**:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("")
public class View {

    @Autowired
    PController controller;
    List<User> users;

    /**
     * After user coin choice is filled with details, it arrives here.
     *
     * @param httpEntity the http entity
     * @return the string
     */
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String arriveAfterSetup(
            HttpEntity<String> httpEntity,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "name") String name,
            @RequestParam(required = false, value = "age") String age,
            final ModelMap modelMap
    ) {
        modelMap.put("elementList", controller.getDatabase().getPersonLinkedList());
        return "main/mainpage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String exchangeViewAfterEdit(ModelMap modelMap
    ) {
        modelMap.put("elementList", controller.getDatabase().getPersonLinkedList());
        return "main/mainpage";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void editPerson(ModelMap modelMap,
                           @PathVariable String id,
                           @RequestParam("name") String name,
                           @RequestParam("age") Double age
    ) {
        //update db
    }



    // @RequestBody - Convert the json data into object (SearchCriteria) mapped by field name.
    // @JsonView(Views.Public.class) - Optional, limited the json data display to client.
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/search/api/getSearchResult")
    public AjaxResponseBody getSearchResultViaAjax(@RequestBody SearchCriteria search) {
        System.out.println("in getSearchResultViaAjax");
        AjaxResponseBody result = new AjaxResponseBody();

        if (isValidSearchCriteria(search)) {
            List<User> users = findByUserNameOrEmail(search.getUsername(), search.getEmail());

            if (users.size() > 0) {
                result.setCode("200");
                result.setMsg("");
                result.setResult(users);
            } else {
                result.setCode("204");
                result.setMsg("No user!");
            }

        } else {
            result.setCode("400");
            result.setMsg("Search criteria is empty!");
        }

        //AjaxResponseBody will be converted into json format and send back to client.
        return result;

    }

    private boolean isValidSearchCriteria(SearchCriteria search) {

        boolean valid = true;

        if (search == null) {
            valid = false;
        }

        if ((StringUtils.isEmpty(search.getUsername())) && (StringUtils.isEmpty(search.getEmail()))) {
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    // Init some users for testing
    @PostConstruct
    private void iniDataForTesting() {
        users = new ArrayList<User>();

        User user1 = new User("mkyong", "pass123", "mkyong@yahoo.com", "012-1234567", "address 123");
        User user2 = new User("yflow", "pass456", "yflow@yahoo.com", "016-7654321", "address 456");
        User user3 = new User("laplap", "pass789", "mkyong@yahoo.com", "012-111111", "address 789");
        users.add(user1);
        users.add(user2);
        users.add(user3);

    }

    // Simulate the search function
    private List<User> findByUserNameOrEmail(String username, String email) {

        List<User> result = new ArrayList<User>();

        for (User user : users) {

            if ((!StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) && (!StringUtils.isEmpty(email))) {

                if (username.equals(user.getUsername()) && email.equals(user.getEmail())) {
                    result.add(user);
                    continue;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }

            }
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(username)) {
                if (username.equals(user.getUsername())) {
                    result.add(user);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                if (email.equals(user.getEmail())) {
                    result.add(user);
                    continue;
                }
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#myInput').focus();
    });

    $("#search-form").submit(function(event) {

        // Disble the search button
        enableSearchButton(false);

        // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
        event.preventDefault();

        searchViaAjax();

    });
});


function searchViaAjax() {

    var search = {}
    search["username"] = $("#username").val();
    search["email"] = $("#email").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "${home}/search/api/getSearchResult",
        data: JSON.stringify(search),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("DONE");
            enableSearchButton(true);
        }
    });

}

function enableSearchButton(flag) {
    $("#btn-search").prop("disabled", flag);
}

function display(data) {
    var json = "<h4>Ajax Response</h4><pre>"
        + JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) + "</pre>";
    $('#feedback').html(json);
}

function searchAjax() {
    var data = {}
    data["query"] = $("#query").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "${home}search/api/getSearchResult",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        timeout: 100000,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("SUCCESS: ", data);
            display(data);
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
            display(e);
        },
        done: function (e) {
            console.log("DONE");
        }
    });
}
```

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"${home}/search/api/getSearchResult"` in `searchViaAjax` seems very odd.

`${home}` looks like a template string, but it's not being replaced, you can tell since your error message says: `"path": "/$%7Bhome%7D/search/api/getSearchResult"`

Comment: I tried several ways like:
url: "/search/api/getSearchResult"
url: "search/api/getSearchResult"
All were failing

Comment: @AnnaKlein Do you mean that you don't know where your contoller actions are being hosted?

Comment: I mean that the controller method getSearchResultViaAjax is not hit by AJAX